# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException amazon web services ec2

Tags: java, amazon-ec2

I am new to java programming and I have been trying to start an aws EC2 instance using a java program that i have written using help from various websites, but I can't seem to succeed after 2 days of trying.

Here is my java code

```
    `public class StartInstancesRequest extends Amamzon WebServiceRequest implements java.io.Serializable,java.lang.Cloneable, DryRunSupportedRequest<StartInstancesRequest>{`

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private static ClientConfiguration credentials;

        @Override
        public Request<StartInstancesRequest> getDryRunRequest() {      

                    return null;
        }   

          public static void main(String[] args)
          {
              AmazonEC2Client ec2 = new AmazonEC2Client(credentials); 
                RunInstancesRequest runInstancesRequest = new RunInstancesRequest();

                      runInstancesRequest.withImageId("ami-96f1c1c4")
                                         .withInstanceType("t2.micro")
                                         .withMinCount(1)
                                         .withMaxCount(1)
                                         .withKeyName("development")
                                         .withSecurityGroups("DevelopmentTesting");

                      RunInstancesResult res = ec2.runInstances(runInstancesRequest); 
                      System.out.println(res.toString());
                      return;
          }
        public static ClientConfiguration getCredentials() {
            return credentials;
        }
        public static void setCredentials(ClientConfiguration credentials) {
            StartInstancesRequest.credentials = credentials;
        }
 }
```

and when i run the program i get this in my console

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.HttpClientFactory.createHttpClient(HttpClientFactory.java:92)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.(AmazonHttpClient.java:200)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:129)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.(AmazonEC2Client.java:196)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.(AmazonEC2Client.java:173)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.(AmazonEC2Client.java:101)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.StartInstancesRequest.main(StartInstancesRequest.java:25)

Can anyone help me? Am I writing the code right??

Comment: It looks like you have provided a null credentials object when creating your AmazonEC2Client object. I don't see a call to setCredentials() anywhere. Where are your credentials coming from? Have you tried ec2 = new AmazonS3Client() without passing any credentials object (this will get you the default credential provider chain)?

Answer (score 0):

You passed in `null` credentials into

```
          AmazonEC2Client ec2 = new AmazonEC2Client(credentials);
```

Causing the NullPointerException.

Comment: Yes, I was new to java as well as AWS API, resolved it, I asked the question 4 months ago. :) Thanks for the effort though.